# Erro Deploy Heroku - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

Fala Galera, beleza? Entao, estou fazendo um deploy no Heroku de uma app que nao tinha conexao com o Mongo, ela estava online,mas sem conexao com alguma base de Dados. Fiz a conexao testei as requisiçoes em localhost com o Mlab e tudo nos trincos...Subi pro GIT e Quebrou a APP no Heroku.Ela esta me retornado o erro da imagem. Procurei algo, mas nao consegui ir a fundo nos logs da Heroku por inexperiencia mesmo com a plataforma.
Caso alguem possa me ajudar o repositorio no Git e esse aqui: 
https://github.com/RhaymisonCristian/darkroomchat
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente, o problema está no seu aplicativo. Verifique para ver se não há nenhum aviso/erro no seu código.

> (...) desc="App crashed"

Você tentou importar o buildpack dentro da Heroku na aba settings?

Comment: Fala CharlieBrow, entao esta com o a heroku/nodejs..Eu rodei um debugger, mas nada e retornado de erro...e como disse a app roda suavao em local.

Comment: Entao, Foi resolvido, realmente tem que dar uma olhada muito fina no codigo...E foram um  uma " que eu havia colocado em um local errado dentro do Server.js.

Comment: Que bom! Você poderia marcar minha resposta como certo?